# YQL Console gives different results than rest query

Tags: javascript, yql

My yql query is as follows:

> select * from xml where url='myurl'

When i use the YQL console, this query gives me the proper, timely, result. However, when using the associated rest query:

> https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22myurl%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=

The result is often ~4 hours out of date. On trying to reload the rest query, it fluctuates back and forth between multiple, several hours outdated, data.

I'm completely at a loss here.
Any suggestions?

Thanks!